# change position grid when minimize

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i wanna ask if there any way to change the grid position when we minimize the screen

example:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6 -col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">//first image
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 -col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">//second image
  </div>
</div>
```

normaly if we minimize the screen until sm or xs-screen it will like this

```
--------
|first |
|      |
|second|
--------
```

how to make like this

```
--------
|second|
|      |
|first |
--------
```

i dont know if it can be done with jquery or not, and i know nothing about jquery. please help me guys

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery resize event.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-6 col-xs-12">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" id="img1">//second image
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6 col-md-pull-6 col-xs-12">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" id="img2">//first image
   </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
   $(window).bind('resize', function () {
            var img1Src = $('#img1').attr('src');
            $('#img1').attr('src', $('#img2').attr('src'));
            $('#img2').attr('src', img1Src);
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

Bootstrap is 'mobile first', then you must think first for the mobile version then for other version.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-6 col-xs-12">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">//second image
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6 col-md-pull-6 col-xs-12">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">//first image
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry but the design is like that. but i have to follow the order sir

Comment: If you want to change the position of the two images in sm/xs-size, this is the solution.